# Unable to fade in/out using MediaElementSource and AudioParam interface in Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to make fade in / fade out effects using a given HTMLAudio element.
To use Web Audio API's AudioParam interface for that purpose, I wrapped the HTMLAudio element around a MediaElementSource node and connect it to a Gain node.
The following code works perfectly in desktop Chrome browser.
However, it doesn't work in Android Chrome. (the sound doesn't diminish but stops abruptly after 2 seconds.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <button disabled>Play</button>
  <script>
    var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
    var audioElem = new Audio();
    audioElem.src = 'bgm.mp3';
    var ctx = new AudioContext();
    var sourceNode = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audioElem);
    var gainNode = ctx.createGain();
    sourceNode.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(ctx.destination);
    audioElem.addEventListener('canplay', function () {
      button.disabled = false;
    }, false);

    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
      if (button.textContent === 'Play') {
        // Fade in
        audioElem.play();
        fade(0, 1, 2)
        .then(function () {
          button.textContent = 'Pause';
          button.disabled = false;
        });
      } else {
        // Fade out
        fade(1, 0, 2)
        .then(function () {
          audioElem.pause();
          button.textContent = 'Play';
          button.disabled = false;
        });
      }
      button.disabled = true;
    }, false);

    function fade(start, end, duration) {
      return new Promise(function (pFulfill, pReject) {
        // Fade in/out using AudioParam interface.
        gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(start, ctx.currentTime);
        gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(end, ctx.currentTime + duration);
        setTimeout(function () {
          pFulfill();
        }, duration * 1000);
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Does anyone know any workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug in Android Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=240415.

Answer (score 0):

Worth mentioning that you can set the volume of a video element like:

```
$('video').volume = 0.5
```